# Pandas load dataframe from MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, record-linkage

I am trying to load the data to the dataframe so I could use it later on in recordlinkage, however I get the error:

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [FirstName, LastName, CompanyName]
Index: []

And I am not sure that I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
import pymssql
import time

import recordlinkage
import pandas.io.sql as psql



#SQL connection
conn = pymssql.connect(host='server', user='xx', password='xx', database='Test')
cursor = conn.cursor()


print(time.ctime())


sql = "select FirstName, LastName, CompanyName, ID from [Test].[dbo].[Person]with(nolock) where ID < 100"





dfA = psql.read_sql(sql, conn,  index_col='ID')
print(dfA)

# Indexation step

pcl = recordlinkage.index.Block(on='FirstName')
pairs = pcl.index(dfA)

# Comparison step
compare_cl = recordlinkage.Compare()

compare_cl.exact('FirstName', 'FirstName', label='FirstName')
compare_cl.string('LastName', 'LastName', method='jarowinkler', threshold=0.85, label='LastName')
compare_cl.string('CompanyName', 'CompanyName', threshold=0.85, label='CompanyName')

features = compare_cl.compute(pairs, dfA)

# Classification step
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 3]

print(len(matches))

print(matches)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part was returning error that there is not data in DataFrame
to fix that change > 3 to > 2 or >1

```
matches = features[features.sum(axis=1) > 3]
```